# Can Array.push Fail?

Tags: evm

Is it possible that Array.push to fail?

I noticed we never check whether it fails or not and thought it can be a vulnerability if an adversary makes it fail.

Comment: Yes, as a result of out of gas, for example.

Comment: But you don't need to check it, because the function will simply revert (i.e., the check-line will not be reached).

Comment: I think this is the answer, go ahead and write this please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible that it fails (i.e. out of gas exception) but the transaction will revert so you don't need to check it.